# Update- Error message : "Cannot switch on a value of type String[]. Only convertible int values, Strings or enum variables are permitted"

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement, joptionpane

I have now changed switch(choices) to switch(input) as suggested and it has removed the previous error message I was getting. But the program is not running as it should.

It creates a pane with a drop down menu, listing 1-5 as options but when I select choices 1, 2, or 4 it doesn't do anything. It is supposed to display the information from the corresponding methods. I'm not sure how to fix this.

When I select option 3 it displays the input boxes as it should but it doesn't matter what I enter it gives the same result. I believe this is because they are initialized to 0, but I'm not sure how I can initialise it without a number.

Also when I select option 5 it is supposed to exit the program, but it does not and again I don't know how to fix this.

any advice?

Methods:

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class System_Y3881268 
{
    // the attributes
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int speed;
    private int memorySize;
    private double hardDiskSize;
    private double purchaseCost;

     // the methods

     // the constructor
    public System_Y3881268(String makeIn, String modelIn, int speedIn) 
    {
        make = makeIn;
        model = modelIn;
        speed = 2;
    }

    // methods to set the corresponding attributes- mutator methods
        public void setMemory(int memorySizeIn) 
        {
            memorySize = memorySizeIn;
        }

        public void setHardDisk(double hardDiskSizeIn) 
        {
            hardDiskSize = hardDiskSizeIn;
        }

        public void setPurchaseCost(double purchaseCostIn) 
        {
            purchaseCost = purchaseCostIn;
        }

    // methods to return attribute values- accessor methods
    public String getMake() 
    {
        return make;
    }

    public String getModel() 
    {
        return model;
    }

    public int getProcessorSpeed() 
    {
        return speed;
    }

    //display details of the system
    public void displayDetails() 
    {
        System.out.println("*****Computer Details*****");
        System.out.println("Make: " + getMake());
        System.out.println("Model: " + getModel());
        System.out.println("Processor speed; " + getProcessorSpeed() + "GHz");
        System.out.println("Memory size: " + memorySize + " MB"); 
        System.out.println("Hard disk size: " + hardDiskSize + " GB");
        System.out.println("Purchase cost: £" + purchaseCost);
    }

    //check if the hard disk size is below 2GB and print corresponding message   
    public String checkHDStatus(double hardDiskSizeIn) 
    {
        if(hardDiskSizeIn<2) 
        {
            return("Low");
        }

        else 
        {
            return("Ok");
        }
    }

    //Check if the memory size is below 128MB and print corresponding message
    public boolean goodMemorySize(int memorySizeIn) 
    {
        if(memorySizeIn<128) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*use the checkHDStatus() method and the goodMemorySize() method to diagnose the 
     * system by displaying the appropriate messages*/
    public void diagnoseSystem() 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*****System Diagnosis*****");
        System.out.println("Hard disk size = " + checkHDStatus(hardDiskSize));
        System.out.println("Memory size Ok = " + goodMemorySize(memorySize));
    }

    //method to display system properties
    public static void displaySystemProperties() 
    {
        Properties pros = System.getProperties();
        pros.get(System.out);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("*****System Properties*****");

        System.out.println("Operating System Architecture: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        System.out.println("Operating System Name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println("Operating System Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
        System.out.println("User Account Name: " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        System.out.println("Java Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println();

        if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Windows 10")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Thumbs up! Your operating system is Windows 10");
        }
        else if(System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Linux")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Thumbs down! Your operating system is Linux");
        } 

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Your choice of operating system is ok");
        }

    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SystemTestGUI_Y3881268 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System_Y3881268 s=new System_Y3881268("Lenovo", 
                "Ideacentre A340-24IWL", 2);
        s.setHardDisk(2);
        s.setMemory(128);
        s.setPurchaseCost(599);

        s.displayDetails();
        s.diagnoseSystem();
        System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }

            private void createGUI() {

                char choice = 0;
                do {
                    String[] choices = { "Select...", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
                    String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select a choice\n1: Print System Details\n2: Diagnose "
                            + "System\n3: Set Details\n4: Print System Properties\n5: Quit the Program", 
                            "Computer System Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);

                    switch(input) 
                    {

                    case "1": 
                    {
                        s.displayDetails();
                    }
                    break;

                    case "2": 
                    {
                        s.diagnoseSystem();
                    }
                    break;

                    case "3": 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter hard disk size in GB: ");
                        double hardDiskSize = 0;
                        s.setHardDisk(hardDiskSize);
                        if(hardDiskSize<2) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hard disk size = Low");
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hard disk size = Ok");
                        }

                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter memory size in MB: ");
                        int memorySize = 0;
                        s.setMemory(memorySize);
                        if(memorySize<128) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Memory Ok = False");
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Memory Ok = True");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                    case "4": 
                    {
                        System_Y3881268.displaySystemProperties();
                    }
                    break;

                    case "5": break;
                    default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter only numbers from 1 - 5");

            }
        }while(choice != '5');


            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: you are trying to perform a switch on an array of Strings, while you can switch on a single String, not on an array. Change this: switch(choices)  to switch(input)

Comment: Thank you. The error is gone. but the program still doesn't work properly

Comment: what is the new error/problem?

Comment: after your update, sorry to say, that we can't help with, because you don't show what you do in those methods.

Answer (score 1):

A few fixes, but, since you don't show your entire code, it won't be complete.

Your first problem, is caused by trying to switch over an array of Strings, instead of over a String.

This:

```
String[] choices = { "Select...", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select a choice\n1: Print System Details\n2: Diagnose System\n3: Set Details\n4: Print System Properties\n5: Quit the Program", "Computer System Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);    
switch (choices) {
  case "1": { s.displayDetails();}
  break;
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
String[] choices = { "Select...", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select a choice\n1: Print System Details\n2: Diagnose System\n3: Set Details\n4: Print System Properties\n5: Quit the Program", "Computer System Menu", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);    
switch (input) { // switch on the value you want to check, the one you entered yourself
  case "1":  s.displayDetails(); // there is no need for { and } here, it just adds lines in your code
  break;
```

Now, this will solve your original problem.

A next problem, is in your while loop:

```
while (choice != '5');
```

choice will never be '5', because you never update the value of choice.
An option would be to change this to:

```
while (!"5".equals(input));
```

since you already have the `input` variable, and can compare that as well.

As I said, you don't show your entire code, so it's hard to check for everything.

Answer (score -1):

Change `switch(choices)` in `switch(input)`.

Comment: you may want to add some more clarification as to why.

Comment: Your "answer" already appears in a comment to the original question.